# Substitute Proxy exception

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

When `Proxy` traps an assignment and doesn't confirm it, in case of strict mode `TypeError` is thrown. But I'm going to misuse proxy and need a `ReferenceError` instead.

How can I get `ReferenceError` in the second call?

```js
var code = `
  try {
    a = 1;
    console.log("Ok");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.name);
  }
`;

var p = new Proxy({a:undefined}, {set(){}});

with (p) (function () {               eval(code); })(); // Ok
with (p) (function () { 'use strict'; eval(code); })(); // TypeError
         (function () { 'use strict'; eval(code); })(); // ReferenceError
```

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/729217/178988)

Comment: Does `throw new ReferenceError(…)` work?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't confirm it"?

Comment: @Ryan, in what place? I need a error only if caller is in strict mode, otherwise nothing should happen. And the `code` should not be changed.

Comment: @Bergi, `{set(){}}` - causes error if setter is called from code in strict mode (only), and by confirming I mean `{set(){return true}}` - assignment is considered successful and no errors occur.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Detecting whether the caller is in strict mode doesn’t look possible. What’s this for? A gag library?

Comment: @Ryan, some king of gag code, actually some sandbox for something like mutation testing. I do not need detecting, I want an other kind of exception. Compare first and second - the firs has no strict mode and has no exception; the second differs only by strict mode and there is an exception. The problem is that I want `ReferenceError` like in third, but get `TypeError`.

Comment: I’d use a JavaScript parser to do that (esprima + escodegen) instead of abusing proxies.

Answer (score 0):

The strict mode `ReferenceError` happens only when there is no such variable `a`. In `with ({a: …}) a = …;`, there always is one. A proxy around the object that only intercepts assignments doesn't change anything about this.

The only thing you can do is to remove the `a` property from your object, or let your proxy behave as if it didn't have such a property: `new Proxy({a: …}, {has(){ return false; }})`. Those both will lead to a `ReferenceError` in strict mode. However, this also means that in sloppy mode they will lead to the creation of a global variable, which might not be desired.

The strict mode `TypeError` happens only when the variable is deemed immutable, e.g. a `const` or, for a `with` statement, a non-writable property - a data property with `writable: false`, an accessory property without a setter, or any other object like a proxy on which `[[Set]]` returns `false`. To avoid it, `return true` from the `set` trap or use the default trap that assigns the property on the target object.

Those two exceptions are the only ones which depend on strict mode, and you can't intercept them but only direct them through other behaviour of your proxy. And of course you can also just throw exceptions from your traps, but those won't depend on strict mode.

Comment: I'm interested in scope isolation, so removing proxy (or key in it) isn't what I want.

Comment: @Qwertiy I don't see anything wrong with just always throwing on every access of global variables for that. If you want to isolate scopes, it doesn't matter whether the code runs in strict mode or not - assigning to an undeclared variable is always a mistake.

Comment: reading of unasssigned variable is always an error. But assignment of it is only an error in strict mode.